# toggle text of button with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<button class="btn hide_show">Don't show text</button>
```

---

```
$(".hide_show").toggle(function () {
    $(this).text("Show text");
}, function () {
    $(this).text("Don't show text");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x83qg/1/

I don't know exactly why this code doesn't work. The idea is toggle the text of the button

Comment: `.toggle()` isn't an event listener but a function. You should replace `.toggle()` by `.click()`. Then, make a test on the displayed text. If text, hide it, else, display it.

Comment: If you're having trouble with a particular jQuery function why not look at the documentation for that function to see if you're using it correctly?

Comment: Your code is working just fine! See this update: http://jsfiddle.net/x83qg/6/ . Problem however is because you use toggle. If hidden, how would you see the changed text?

Comment: @abhitalks - The code certainly _isn't_ working fine given that it doesn't do what the OP wants. The button's visibility isn't supposed to be toggled - the OP is trying to use the [_other_ `.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Comment: @nnnnnn: That is exactly what I was trying to convey. Op wanted to change text which is actually happening. However, the problem is in `toggle`! He was unable to see because toggle was hiding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toggle` function you have executes on `DOM` ready and hides the button and there is no way to show it again. You probably need to change the text of click.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x83qg/7/)**

```
$(".hide_show").click(function () {
   $(this).text( $(this).text() == "Show text" ? "Don't show text" :"Show text");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery originally had two `.toggle()` functions. One [toggles visibility](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), and the other sets up a [click handler that toggles between multiple handlers](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). Which function was used depended on what arguments were passed in. It seems to be the latter that you are trying to use, but it was deprecated in v1.8 and *removed* in v1.9.

Fortunately it's pretty easy to implement something like the removed `.toggle()`:

```
var text = ["Show text", "Don't show text"],
    i = 0;
$(".hide_show").click(function () {
    $(this).text(text[i]);
    i = (i + 1) % text.length;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x83qg/12/

Note that (like the old `.toggle()` function that allowed more than two handlers) the code I've shown will cycle through all items in the array, so you're not restricted to just switching back and forth between only two items.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var txt = $(".hide_show").text().toLowerCase();
if(txt == "show text"){
    $(".hide_show").text("Don't show text");
}
else{
    $(".hide_show").text("Show text");
}
```

[**DEMO here**](http://jsfiddle.net/x83qg/11/)